# jquery not working without page refresh Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and trying to use jquery ( add class onclick),
its working whenever we refresh the page but whenever i come to page after any menu click ( not refresh) then jquery not working ( add class onclick not working),How can i do this ? Here is my current code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".PrivateSwitchBase-input-6").on('click', function(sss){
            $(".MuiFormControlLabel-root").removeClass("active"); 
        $(this).parents('.MuiFormControlLabel-root').addClass("active");
      });
    });
```

Comment: Do not use jQuey/ JS to add events if you are using React. Use React to do it

Comment: jQuery works nicely when you have a static HTML DOM and want to sprinkle simple interactivity on the page like click, scroll, animation, etc. React operates on a completely different model where there's practically no static HTML DOM and everything is created dynamically via JavaScript. The two won't always play nicely each other. Like @Rajesh noted above, whatever you use jQuery for had better be done via React/JavaScript methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Jquery with React at the same time is not a good idea. Overall, you should avoid having two things modify the DOM, since it creates hard to maintain code and instability (It's hard to tell what is modifying what!). I think you can achieve what you're trying to do with an `onClick` event and conditional classes. Something like:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    
    const App = () => {
      const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    
      return (
        <div className="box">
          <div className={`.MuiFormControlLabel-root ${active ? "active" : ""}`}>
            I am some div
          </div>
          <button onClick={() => setActive(!active)}>Click here!</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Here is a codepen if you want to see it in action: https://codepen.io/Chanodev/pen/gOjmgwa

But, if you want to go the jquery route, the best idea is to get some part of the DOM that is not manipulated by React, as demonstrated in https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#how-to-approach-the-problem.

```
    import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react"

    const App = () => {
      const el = useRef(null)
      useEffect(() => {
        //Do stuff with 'el' HTMLElement here. You could also call the 
        //  proposed code here, but manipulating DOM with 
        //  both React and Jquery is a bad idea. 
        /*$(".PrivateSwitchBase-input-6").on('click', function(sss){
                $(".MuiFormControlLabel-root").removeClass("active"); 
            $(this).parents('.MuiFormControlLabel-root').addClass("active");
          }); */
        return () => {
        //Cleanup stuff with 'el'. Destroy jquery listeners. 
    }
      }, [])
      return(
         <div ref={el}>Hello</div>
      );
    }
```

A few good links:

- State on react: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
- Event handling: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html
- Conditional styling: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html